# How to control layout in different parts of syntax?

Tags: rascal

I am looking at the Exp example in the Tutorial.

Is it possible to control layout conditionally?  Consider, for example, Python expressions:

- Newlines are irrelevant while inside a parenthesized expression
- Otherwise, a newline is a statement/expression terminator

For example:
 (1 + \n 3)

is a valid expression, but
 1 +\n 3

is not.

If not, what would be the easiest way of achieving the same result, short of sprinkling newlines through my grammar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

- if you use a `layout` non-terminal `L` in a `syntax` rule between two normal symbols `A` and `B` like so: syntax NY = "foo" A L B "bar", then Rascal will not add more layout non-terminals between the `A` and `L` or between `L` and `B`
- you can add layout non-terminals to your grammar which are not automatically inserted all the time (for use in the first point) like so: `layout NoNewLineLayout = @manual [\t\ ]*;`

So this requires sprinkling instances of NoNewLineLayout symbols in your grammar, rather than sprinkling newlines. I normally use a short name like NNL to make this less intrusive. We used this workaround for experimenting with Javascript grammars and other layout sensitive languages. In general, though it is not perfect and we've been working more elegant solutions, see http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2814242 for a preview.

A second less flexible solution is to use the scope of `layout` definitions (which is module scoped). The layout definition in the current module takes precedence over any imported layout definitions. In such a way one can influence which layout non-terminal is woven in which rules. This comes mostly in handy when embedding languages into other languages which may have different comment conventions and such; for the current use case, I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I considered using the scope of the layout definitions, by defining expressions in e.g. expr.rsc and then using expr_w.rsc which adds the newline layout and the bracketed expression, and then composing my final syntax from the two, but I couldn't get it to work.  I will try the other suggestions.

Comment: (Sorry, had to split for length) Finally, as another possibility:  Since you mention that layout can contain non-terminals:  Could have an action on parens, which will set a flag on entry/exit, and then use a non-terminal action on the layout, and "fail" the parse if "\n" is included outside of parens?

Comment: Rascal grammars do not have side-effects, so that can't be done. You could write a post-parse filter however: see http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Rascal.html#/Rascal/Declarations/SyntaxDefinition/Action/Action.html  . These are just parse tree patterns applied when building the tree which allow you to rewrite it as its being constructed, or to filter alternatives which you care to drop. It's slower than fixing the grammar and depending on the filter code can be too slow. It's also hard to comprehend usually. I prefer the data-dependent solution by Afroozeh and Izmaylova, which we will add.